# Sort files and folders correctly on Sublime Text 3/Mac

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there any way to make Sublime Text 3 sort files and folders correctly in the sidebar?

At the moment they're sorted Windows-style, with folders appearing first.

Is there a setting or plugin to make the sidebar work like the rest of the operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, changing the sort order in the sidebar is not currently possible (as at build 3131).

There are open feature requests for it here:

- https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/721
- https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/328